# Is there a navigation package that works with drones (3d)?

Tags: navigation, 3d-navigation, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working on autonomous drone flight for a search and rescue concept. I know how to create a 3d costmap but what can I do for 3d navigation? Preferably on Indigo but I'll take what I can get at this point.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241845/is-there-a-navigation-package-that-works-with-drones-(3d)-?/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2016-08-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i installed ROS indigo, i m using OpenCV do some visual computing. But i could not use the Webcam neither with OpenCV neither with sont site on web. It’s seem to be not detected. Someone know where i can find tuto or information about that ? or does someones already had this problem ?

---

Originally posted by [Fixithere](https://answers.ros.org/users/21219/fixithere/) with karma: 36 on 2016-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2016-08-17**:
Please do not ask questions as an answer to a question. That question also seems unrelated to ROS. If it is ROS-related, please give more details.

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-08-17**:
@Fixithere I see you're new to this Stack Exchange style Q&A. You accidentally asked a "Question" in the form of an "Answer" to a question I had already asked which was quite confusing to me at first. In order to ask a NEW question you want to click the `"ASK YOUR QUESTION"` button (top right)